# Specifying twist and scale as a function for linear extrusion in OpenSCAD

Tags: function, parameters, parameter-passing, cad, openscad

I am a bit surprised that I cannot find an option to specify the scale and twist parameter for the `linear_extrusion()` function as functions themselves. But only as scalars or vectors. That is quite a serious limitation. Which surprises me considering the mathematical approach OpenSCAD takes on modelling.

Did I miss something?

Currently I have to use a loop as a workaround. It creates 1000 solids of the same shape that are extruded slightly and twisted and scaled different for each iteration. This works, creates a usable surface in the preview. But rendering hangs, also SDL export, and I can only assume that is due to the number of solids I create?

Is there any other workaround or alternative?

I found an implementation of `linear_extrude_fs()` and `linear_extrude_ft()` trying to implement this, but internally the same workaround is used. Plus it is an "ugly" solution, since due to compiler resolution I'd have to modify that module directly for each modification of shape or parameter.

Comment: Update: I found out that exporting to SDL format did _not_ actually hang, but only took quite a long time to compute...

Answer (score 0):

```
linear_extrude(height = 50, center = true, convexity = 10, twist = -110, slices = 20, scale = 10.0, $fn = 16)
translate([2, 0, 0])
circle(r = 1);
```

You can find more examples in this page:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/2D_to_3D_Extrusion

Happy hacking!

Comment: I fail to understand what you are trying to offer here. What I asked about above is "to specify the scale and twist parameter [...] as functions". In your answer you don't do that, you hand over numerical values, so fixed scalars. Which is obviously possible, but not what I ask about. Did I miss something in your answer?